# ul li based menu with automatic overflow?

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

currently I'm developing simple website for my client. Right now i have a problem with ul/li generated menu. Page is 900px, menu font is quite large, about 30px, also wide horizontal margins. I want to menu items, go do second row, where there is no space left (about 5 items fit well in one line). Between lines of menu items where is an image I've used "margin-bottom: 226px" to achieve correct position of the second menu items line. And here is the problem, because of that high margin, menu is overlapping on  and nothing can be clicked or selected. I tryed z index to popup content layer, but it didnt worked. Anything that is above red line is unclickable.

Do you know another way to achieve such an result with two lines of menu items that avoid above mentioned overlapping problem?

This is css[image]

```
/* Main navigation menu */
#nav {
    float: none;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
    background: none!important;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    /*height: auto;*/
    margin-top: 35px;
    **margin-bottom: 226px;**
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
/*  letter-spacing: 5px;*/

}
```

Comment: try min and max width

Comment: Can be done easily if you put up a fiddle. (jsfiddle)

Comment: If you could link to a page where it is not working correctly or create a JSFiddle or JSBin to show what's wrong, it will be much easier to determine the problem and figure out a solution.

Comment: Hello, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infografik/CG4X7/5/

Comment: The simplest answer is to break to break the top and bottom menus into two separate `ul` elements.

Comment: Well it would require modyfing php code, and I'm not up to it. How to do this in css?